# Closed form of $I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx $ and is it behave similar with error function?

Tags: closed-form, applications, error-function, universal-property

$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$
The computation of $\int_{0}^{a}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$ for large $a$ gives $0.972106...$ by wolfram alpha, but 
according to  **JJacquelin** comments which claimed that $I(a)=\int_{0}^{a}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$  is a  non-standard special function ,and according to the comments of **yuriy** which showed that is a just a constant , then it must to ask about closed form of

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx $$ if it exists with $a$ positive real number , and also to know if this special function behave as the same with Error function or exponontial function since it is a composition of them ? and what about it's application in probability and in differential equation area ? **In addition of that what about  representation of it's hypergeometric function** ?

**Edit 01:**  I have edited the question according to the below comments and to know the closed form of this special function since it is not standard .

**Edit 02** I have added some detaill in my question according to the good answer which is gaven by **yuriy** in order to know more about this new function

**Edit:** I have added other question which seking for the hypergeometric function of the titled function .

**Note (01):**$\erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt.$

**Note (02):** The motivation of this function is to look for the behavior of integral of some functions where they are represented as a function power it's antiderivative function however the example we take here is :$\int ({f'})^{kf}$ .

Comment: Why do you think a closed form exists?

Comment: May I ask how you did arrive to this integral ?

Comment: Thanks to the special function :$$Z_{\text{era}}(x)=\int_0^x \left(e^{-t^2}\right)^{\erf(t)}dt\:,$$
the closed form you are looking for is $Z_{\text{era}}(\infty)$ :
$$\int_0^\infty \left(e^{-t^2}\right)^{\erf(t)}dt=Z_{\text{era}}(\infty)\simeq 0.972106992769179...$$
Note : The special function $Z_{\text{era}}(x)$ is not standard. As far as I now, no bibliographic reference is available yet.

Comment: what do you meant by z_era(x) ?

Comment: @YuriyS, no it's not a constant , try for example integration from x=0 to 1 is not 0.97

Comment: What do you mean? You have this expression in the title and in the body of the question: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$$ Which is a constant

Comment: I meant that is not constant for every real x , but for it's form is constant

Comment: If you want the closed form for the integral with a variable limit: $$I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$$ you should edit the question accordingly. So far your question is asking about the constant

Comment: probably , it's a new special function, what about it's application in mathematics and how do you can using it ?

Comment: Comment about the edit: please note that $ \erf (x)$ is not the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$, that would be $\frac{\sqrt{ \pi}}{2} \erf (x)$ because the error function is defined together with a constant factor to make it go to $1$ at $\infty$

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: The wording of your question is not correct because $\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$ is not a function, it is a constant. $\int_{0}^{x}{(e^{-t²})}^{\erf(t)}dt$ is a function as written in my first comment. Don't confuse both, they are very different. You should edit again your question.

Comment: yes, i have edited it earlier , i know that for large x this will be a constant and we are interesting in the closed form of it as a function, thanks

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik : You wrote  ...which claimed that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(e^{-x²})}^{\erf(x)}dx$  is a  non-standard special function. This is false. What is written in my comment is very different : $\int_{0}^{x}{(e^{-t²})}^{\erf(t)}dt$ is a  non-standard special function. Doesn't confuse both. If you can understand this will be an important progress for you.

Comment: Ah, sorry , just a wrong typo i have to edit it

Comment: @JJacquelin , The same history that i have passed in the past year with :https://oeis.org/A214645 , which it is a new O.D.E (formel series) , really i'm a men who is love research

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, i'm interesting for it's closed form, pleas could you allow me to share the question in mathoverflow ?

Comment: @JackWonder I don't think if the closed form exist but no problem to share any question about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\erf} {\operatorname{erf}}$I hope this will be helpful to you.

First, abandon the search for closed form. It's not likely it exists.

Now, if you really need a simple expression for $I(a)$ in some range of values, there are ways to get various approximations.

The function is very nice. It goes to its limit at $\infty$ very very fast. Here's the plot of $I(a)$ for $a \in [0,10]$:

[image]

So (depending on the accuracy you need) you can easily take $I(a)=I(\infty)$ for $a > a_0$ with $a_0$ around $3$ or $4$.

Mathematica gives for the first $100$ digits:

$$I(\infty)=0.972106992769178593151077875442391175554272\\1833855699009722910408441888759958220033410678218401258734$$

---

Now, what to do for small $a$?

The function is so nice, you can just use the Taylor expansion around $a =0$. The first term is:

$$I(a) \approx a$$

Here's the plot for $a \in [0,1]$:

[image]

The proof is simple. The Taylor series look like this:

$$I(a)=I(0)+I'(0) a+\frac{I''(0)}{2!} a^2+\frac{I'''(0)}{3!} a^3+\dots$$

We can see that:

$$I(0)=0$$

$$I'(0)=e^{-a^2 \erf (a) } \bigg| _{a=0}=1$$

Now let's find a better approximation by computing the higher derivatives:

$$I''(a)=\left( e^{-a^2 \erf (a) } \right)'=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} a e^{-a^2 (\text{erf}(a)+1)} \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{a^2} \text{erf}(a)+a\right)$$

$$I''(0)=0$$

---

I use Mathematica as a shortcut, but it's easy to do it by hand, if you remember:

$$\erf' (x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}$$

---

$$I'''(0)=0$$

$$I^{ IV} (0)=-\frac{12}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

---

So our next approximation is:

$$I(a) \approx a-\frac{ 1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} a^4$$

The plot with both approximations (orange, green) and the function itself (blue) is given below:

[image]

You can continue in the same way for higher derivatives.

---

Now I admit that it's possible you need the values of $I(a)$ for all the possible $a$ and with high precision, so the approximations won't do. Then you need to turn to numerical integration (as Mathematica did for me to plot the function).

---

Another way to approximate the function is using its derivative:

$$\frac{d I}{da}=e^{-a^2 \erf (a) }$$

But this is an ordinary differential equation, which can be solved numerically.

As an illustration, here's a simple explicit Euler scheme for the step size $h$:

$$\frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}=e^{-a^2 \erf (a) }$$

$$I(a+h)=I(a)+h e^{-a^2 \erf (a) }$$

We can use an initial value $I(0)=0$.

For $h=\frac{1}{10}$ we have the following result (red dots) compared to the exact function (blue line):

[image]

For $h=\frac{1}{50}$:

[image]

This way can serve as a good alternative to numerical integration (depending on the context and the application of course).

Comment: Thanks for this attractive answer , really i have tried the approximation with small a i  find I(a) almost is a

Comment: I should also guess about it's approximation in elemenatry function

Comment: I saw your edition it is  very good , really it's seems to me to add other question or by edit this question to know in which area this function could be occurs for example error function occurs in probability and stat and PDE , Is that also ?

Comment: pleas explaine more to me , i don't understand what doy you mean by the existing of it application

Comment: ok, Really i was interesting to know integration of a function power it's antiderivative for example  integration of this : (1/x)^(logx), it cames in my mind to ask about integration of e^(-x²) power it's antiderivative to look for the behavior and it's approximation and to know also about it's analyticity an others properties, Does this function behave the same of error function or the same with e^(-x²) since it is a composition of thes function.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, then maybe you can modify your question (adding this information) then you would be able to get a more suitable answer. For what it's worth, you can see that this function behaves more like the error function

Comment: Ok, thanks for that

Comment: I(a)+I_c(a)=1.94421 which is a rational number

Comment: it is a complementary function of I(a) over (-infty, 0)

Comment: I am afraid, I made a mistake in my above comment : The $Z_{\text{era}}(x)$ function better should be the $Y_{\text{uriy}}(x)$ function.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I'm honored, thank you. I'm afraid the OP didn't get your joke :)

Comment: @JJacquelin, i'm honored also since i'm just student learning from you , if Yuriy want to build a paper and submit it to journal i'm willing for helping all with my efforts , In my mind mathematics is the cooperation, i'm find the function and Yuriy made the proof that's so good

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik : Of course this was a joke. I hope you appreciate it.

Comment: @JJacquelin, lol , do you meant that is a standard and that is not a new special function ? lol , really i wish to be our teacher

Comment: @YuriyS, just a small question, why you don't apply Role theorem since I(a)=I(+\infty) for a >3 , all derivative becames 0

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, it's not true. It's only an approximation. The function doesn't become a constant. It just closely approaches a constant