# What is the asymptotic series of :$I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx $ and does it have a complementary function?

Tags: asymptotics, error-function, upper-lower-bounds, universal-property

The same topic of the OP of  this question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2644304/156150) seeking for  closed form of $I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx $  and it's behavior compared to error function, the question is answered nicely and numerically  by Turiy , but in this question I want to know the asymptotic series of :

$I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx $ ? and if it does have a [complementary function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html) as error function ? Does it satisfies any functional equation ? . Only what i have deduced about Bondedness of the titled integral is :

$0\leq I(a)=\int_{0}^a {(e^{-x²})}^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx \leq \operatorname{erf}(x) $ , for $x \geq 0$

Comment: @YuriyS Is it? It does not seem to be.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, I meant asymptotically. See the linked question. It is extremely close to a constant for $a>3$

Comment: Oh, yeah, it is asymptotically constant indeed.

Comment: I guess you mean $\le \text{erf}(a)$ in the last equation?